# android.content.res.Resurces$NotFoundException : String resource ID #0x0

Tags: android, xml

Please help me, I can't figure out why this error. Just a day ago it worked. 
I understand the it serches for and id ist'n existing but the id is there in the xml.
It give me error here, in `onCreate` method:

```
public class DoExamActivity extends Activity {
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private EditText votoET;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.do_exam);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        try {
            transcript = new JSONObject(bundle.getString("transcript"));
            exam = new JSONObject(bundle.getString("exam"));
            teacher = new JSONObject(bundle.getString("teacher"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        votoET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.examValueET); //here
```

This is the `do_exam.xml` of the edit text he cant find. You can see the id is there!

```
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/ios7orange"
                android:contentDescription="@string/textValueDescr"
                android:src="@drawable/rating_star" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/examValueET"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:hint="@string/examValueHint"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1" />
        </TableRow>
```

Give me this error:

```
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.utaa.iesami/com.utaa.iesami.activity.DoExamActivity}:     android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091): Caused by:     android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at     android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:239)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at     android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3844)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at     com.utaa.iesami.activity.DoExamActivity.onCreate(DoExamActivity.java:61)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
11-13 07:04:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     ... 11 more
```

I searched in the R class and the id of that `EditText` is there and is different from 0. So why this error?

**CODE UPDATED**

I already cleaned, nothing. The activity it's too big, I added the code until the row of the error. So I used the caps for all the IDs, it worked for two week, now it give me error just on that ET.

Comment: examValueET should be  examvalueet dont use caps letter in id delcaration

Comment: post the full activity code

Comment: add your string.xml to the question also probably the problem comes from there

Comment: in eclipse, go to Project > Clean… 2.select your project

Comment: @steevoo i used the caps for all the IDs, it gives me error just on thaat EditText.

Comment: The stacktrace shows the crash is in `TextView.setText()` in your `onCreate()` but the code does not show that. Guess: you're calling essentially `setText(0)` on your `EditText`. If you want to set the edittext value to 0, use `setText(String)` instead of `setText(int)`.

Comment: Why does this happen?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

My error. I mistaked the rows, the error was from a `TextView.setText(int)` where I had to set `TextView.setText(String.valueOf(int))`.

Comment: To clarify it's because when you do .setText(int) android is looking in resources (by ID (integer))

Answer (score 22):

Just as @laalto said:

> you're calling essentially setText(0) on your EditText. If you want to set the edittext value to 0, use setText(String) instead of setText(int).

But i assume it's not your fault because the value of int might be dynamic (called from a data source - DB), this was the case for me and i had to box the value of int i.e

instead of

```
setText(int)
```

use

```
setText(String.valueOf(int))
```

Hope this helps you Or someone! Happy Coding!!!